# How to effectively join large tables in SparkSql?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to improve performance on a  join involving two large tables using SparkSql. From various sources, I figured that the RDDs need to be partitioned.

Source: https://deepsense.io/optimize-spark-with-distribute-by-and-cluster-by

However, when you load a file directly from a parquet file as given below, I am not sure how it can be created as a paired RDD!

With Spark 2.0.1, using “cluster by” has no effect.

```
val rawDf1 = spark.read.parquet(“file in hdfs”)
rawDf1 .createOrReplaceTempView(“rawdf1”)

val rawDf2 = spark.read.parquet(“file in hdfs”)
rawDf2 .createOrReplaceTempView(“rawdf2”)

val rawDf3 = spark.read.parquet(“file in hdfs”)
rawDf3 .createOrReplaceTempView(“rawdf3”)

val df1 = spark.sql(“select * from rawdf1 cluster by key)
df1 .createOrReplaceTempView(“df1”)

val df2 = spark.sql(“select * from rawdf2 cluster by key)
df2 .createOrReplaceTempView(“df2”)

val df3 = spark.sql(“select * from rawdf3 cluster by key)
df3 .createOrReplaceTempView(“df3”)

val resultDf = spark.sql(“select * from df1 a inner join df2 b on a.key = b.key inner join df3 c on a.key =c.key”)
```

Whether I use "cluster by" key or not, I still see the same query plan being generated by Spark. How can I create a rdd pair in spark sql so that joins can use tables that can be partitioned?

Without proper partitioning, a lot of shuffles are happening resulting in long delays.

Our configuration ( 5 worker nodes with 1 executor (5 cores per executor) each having 32 cores and 128 GB of RAM):

```
spark.cores.max 25
spark.default.parallelism   75
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions   -XX:+UseG1GC
spark.executor.memory   60G
spark.rdd.compress  True
spark.driver.maxResultSize  4g
spark.driver.memory 8g
spark.executor.cores    5
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions -Djdk.nio.maxCachedBufferSize=262144
spark.memory.storageFraction    0.2
```

To add more info: I am joining more than one table in the same select using the same key across all tables. So it is not possible to create a dataframe first to call repartitionby. I understand I can do this using dataframe api. But my question is how to accomplish this using plain sparksql.

Comment: Interesting no answer given at all, or comment